# How to Copy a Row to a Different Tab based on Column Value When in a Set Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a google sheets tab that tracks designers tasks.

[See Image of Google Sheet Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POzBt.png)

When a designer marks the task "Completed" in column 7, I would like that row to be copied and pasted to a different tab. Once pasted, I would like the original copied row to be cleared. However, I would like the tab that the copied row is sent to be based on a set range on the original tab. This is because I would like to track all the tasks a designer completes on a separate tab. Since I work with 3 designers, I will have 3 different completed tabs; or 3 separate locations for the copied rows to go to.

Below is my current code:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wst = ss.getSheetByName('Tasks');
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  
  //FOR CODE TO MOVE COMPLETED ROWS OF TASKS IN TASKS TAB TO STAFF COMPLETED TABS
  taskstabtoCompleted(ss,s,r,wst);

//Tasks Tab-Moves Task Rows to Completed Task Tabs When Status is Completed
   function taskstabtoCompleted(ss,s,r,wst){
     if(s.getName() == "Tasks" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Completed") {
       if (wst.getRange(3,1,9,7)){
          var row = r.getRow();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Designer 1 Completed Tasks");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);
          var clearRange = s.getRange(row,1,1,7);
          clearRange.clearContent();
       }
       else if (wst.getRange(14,1,9,7)){
          var row = r.getRow();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Designer 2 Completed Tasks");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);
          var clearRange = s.getRange(row,1,1,7);
          clearRange.clearContent();
       }
       else
          var row = r.getRow();
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Designer 3 Completed Tasks");
          var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);
          var clearRange = s.getRange(row,1,1,7);
          clearRange.clearContent();
     }
   }
```

Right now the code is not working at all. I have got it to copy the row by tweaking it slightly, but it would be sent to the first tab mentioned regardless of where it is on the original tab.

Any help would be much appreciated! Let me know if I need to explain myself further.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `However, I would like the tab that the copied row is sent to be based on a set range on the original tab.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: There are three separate tabs for three separate sections:

On the tab titled Tasks if column G in rows 3-11 says "Completed" copy and paste the row to "Designer 1 Completed Tasks" tab and clear the row on the Tasks tab. 

On the tab titled Tasks if column G in rows 14-22 says "Completed" copy and paste the row to "Designer 2 Completed Tasks" tab and clear the row on the Tasks tab. 

Lastly, on the tab titled Tasks if column G in rows 25-33 says "Completed" copy and paste the row to "Designer 3 Completed Tasks" tab and clear the row on the Tasks tab.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, 3 destination sheets are existing and you want to copy the edited row value to each sheet you want. And, you want to append the row value to the last row of each sheet. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet, it will help in thinking of a sample script. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, a sample script would be very helpful! And yes I think you understand. Just to reiterate, I would like to copy and paste a row on the "Task" tab to the last row of one of the three tabs when column G says "Completed. The destination of the row to one of the three tabs is dependent on the row number in the Task tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- In your situation, 3 destination sheets are existing and you want to copy the edited row value to each sheet you want.
- You want to append the row value to the last row of each sheet.
- After the row was copied, you want to clear the row values from the source sheet "Tasks".

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

When I saw your script, I thought that the event object might be able to be taken advantage of more. And also, when an object for searching destination sheet names, I thought that the script might be able to become simple. So, I would like to propose the following sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // This condition is from your reply.
  const obj = {
    "3-11": "Designer 1 Completed Tasks",
    "14-22": "Designer 2 Completed Tasks",
    "25-33": "Designer 3 Completed Tasks",
  };

  const { range, source, value } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Tasks" || range.columnStart != 7 || value != "Completed") return;
  const o = Object.entries(obj).find(([k]) => {
    const [start, end] = k.split("-");
    return range.rowStart >= Number(start) && range.rowStart <= Number(end);
  });
  if (!o) return;
  const r = range.offset(0, -6, 1, 7);
  const dstSheet = source.getSheetByName(o[1]);
  r.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
  r.clearContent();
}
```

- When the dropdown list of column "G" of the "Tasks" sheet is changed to `Completed`, this script is run. The row is copied to the last row of the destination sheet depending on the row number. And, the row value is cleared.

#### Note:

- From `s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);` of your script, if you want to copy the row values with the styles and dropdown list, please modify `r.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });` to `r.copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));`.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: A superior answer. Both answers do exactly the same thing, but this answer provides an excellent guide to simplifying script.

Answer (score 1):

Your script copies data to one of three sheets depending on the row number.

This answer makes more use of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

- #1: `if` statement#1 is the same as the OP

  - #1.1: a series `if else if`  statements follow to check whether the row number falls between the values for each Designer.
- #2: a single set of statements to copy data to the target sheet and clear the source sheet.

---

```
function onEdit(event){
  // var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();      
  var ss = event.source // makes use of Event Object
  var sheet2Watch = 'Tasks'
  var row = event.range.rowStart

  if(event.range.getSheet().getName() == sheet2Watch && event.range.columnStart == 7 && event.value == "Completed") {

    if ((row >= dRows[0][0]) && (row <=dRows[0][1])){ // designer1
      var targetSheetName = "Designer 1 Completed Tasks"
    }
    else if ((row >= dRows[1][0]) && (row <=dRows[1][1])) { // designer 2
      var targetSheetName = "Designer 2 Completed Tasks"
    }
    else if((row >= dRows[2][0]) && (row <=dRows[2][1])){ // designer 3
      var targetSheetName = "Designer 2 Completed Tasks"
    }
    else {
      return
    }
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetName)
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1)
    var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet2Watch)
    sourceSheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 7).copyTo(target);
    var clearRange = sourceSheet.getRange(event.range.rowStart,1,1,7);
    clearRange.clearContent();

  }
}
```

Comment: About `This answer makes more use of Event Objects.`, in this case, how about modifying `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` to `var ss = event.source;`? [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/04/14/benchmark-event-objects-for-google-apps-script/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Old habits are hard to break but this is an obvious candidate for using the Event Object.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of the simple trigger, the maximum execution time is 30 seconds. When the event object is used effectively, the process cost of the script can be reduced. I think that this is one of the important points. And, I think that your proposed script will help understand OP's approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The first answer solved my problem! I will try the second one and get back to you.

Comment: For the second answer it is telling me that "row" is undefined as a const. Not sure how to make that a const without changing the function. Nonetheless, the first answer works, so thank you!

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I wrote the script without any data. I've just added `var row = event.range.rowStart` at the top of the script. That should fix the problem.